# Animate elements when visible with dynamic heights

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I know how to animate elements using css. However I am trying to set up the jQuery so that when the user scrolls down the css animation effect is activated. So basically added to the elements class. I know how to do it based on a set height but I have dynamic content that changes in size and height. How would I do it with the changing height sizes?

I am wanting the css to activate when the element becomes visible in the browser. The code below does this based on a set height, however my content is dynamic.

The code for set heights:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        $('#animatedElement').each(function(){
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
                $(this).addClass("slideUp");
            }
        });
    });
```

**UPDATE**

Please note the code above is not mine but the author at http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/index.html#how .I may of not made myself clear in the question so to explain it better.....

In basic terms I am simply wanting to add a class (for example 'slide') to the div when it becomes visible in the browser. I cannot do so based on the height as the div may be in a different place.

Comment: wich part is dynamic `+400` ? Also why are you doing `each()` for an id selector. **ID must be unique**.

Comment: I need it to be dynamic. I know this isn't dynamic...this isn't my code. It is from http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/index.html#how

Comment: I stated that code is for set heights

Comment: Try using jquery to animate instead of using css. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking @user2966586

Comment: @oscar jara I am wanting the css to animate when the element become visisble in the browser

Comment: @user2966586 Then `CSS` class will replace the `height` of your elements when scrolling right? but I don't get the part where you wrote **"How to do it if my content is dynamic"** is it possible to be more specific here? Also, there are a couple of things which I don't understand, first, why you use `+400`? It doesn't make sense and, second, you are doing `foreach` of elements with the **same ID when, according to `HTML` standards, ID must be unique!** instead you can use `CSS` class for selector. Also, where are you setting the height at first time in your example?

Comment: @OscarJara That code isn't mine but the author of the css classes viewable at justinaguilar.com/animations/index.html#how. I have different heights of each div that might be in different places so having a fixed 400px from the top of the page does not work for me. My divs may be in different places as I have a options panel that can move the elements. In basic terms I am simply wanting to add a class (for example 'slide') to the div when it becomes visible in the browser.

Comment: I found the answer in this question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389701/animate-elements-when-visble-with-dynamic-heights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example. Just change the CSS styles with reference to the `slideUp`class, for example by adding `overflow:hidden` for dynamic, non-fixed heights.

[jQuery: animate element on scroll](http://codepen.io/gabrieleromanato/pen/Glmuo)